# NSTimer in Swift making a label an array value

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode, nstimer

Hello I am trying to take an array I have and update a label to display each element in the array one second apart. An example would be me having the array [3,6,2] and my label would show 3 then wait a second and show 6 then wait a second and show 2. I've seen many NSTimer examples with update functions doing things like this but only with an incrementation on a number, never trying to parse an array. Can anyone help?

### Update

I am calling my timer in a UIButton and am running into a problem. The timer works fine but my code in the button function under my timer runs before the timer and update function. My code below generates a random array of numbers then should display them one second apart. It is doing this correct but my print statement under my timer is running before it updates and displays the numbers in the textbook. I do not know why? Is the timer running on a different thread?

```
func updateCountdown() {
    if(numbersIndex <= numberLimit){
        self.counter.text = String(numbers[numbersIndex])
    }else if(numbersIndex == numberLimit+1){
        self.counter.text = ""
    }else{
        timer!.invalidate()
        timer=nil
    }
    numbersIndex+=1
}


@IBAction func startButton(_ sender: AnyObject){
    startB.setTitle("", for: .normal)
    var highestLength = 3

    //for trialNumber in 0...11{
        var numberSequence = Array(repeating:11, count: highestLength)
        for count in 0...highestLength-1{
            var randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(10))
            if(count>0){
                while(numberSequence.contains(randomNumber) || randomNumber-1 == numberSequence[count-1]){
                    randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(10))
                }
            }
            numberSequence[count] = randomNumber
        }
        print(numberSequence)


        self.numbers = numberSequence
        self.numbersIndex = 0
        self.numberLimit = numberSequence.count-1
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(updateCountdown), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

        print("this should be last")
        //do other stuff too

    //}

}
```

Comment: can you give us the code you've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do something like this.

```
var counter = 0
var list: [String] = ["Eggs", "Milk"]  

override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()

  var timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(self.update), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

}


func update() {
  label.text = "\(list[counter])" 
  counter += 1
  if (counter >= list.count) {
     counter = 0
  }
}
```

this is assumming the name of you Label is label

Comment: I am calling my timer in a UIButton and am running into a problem. The timer works fine but my code in the button function under my timer runs before the timer and update function. Do you know why this is?

Comment: not sure I completely understand your question. Please post the code

Comment: Just updated and posted my code could you see if you can help, thanks.